# Existence of a numerable family given a element of a $\sigma-$algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to prove the next stament:

Let $E\subset\mathcal{P}(X)$ fixed. Then for all $A\in\sigma(E),$ there exists a numerable subfamily $E_{0}\subset E$ such that $A\in \sigma(E_{0}).$

My attempt is based on the follow: Let $S=\bigcup\{\sigma(E^{'}):E^{'}\subset E \quad\text{is numerable}\}.$ I've proved that $S$ is a $\sigma-$algebra. Then, I'd like to show that $E \subset S$ to prove that $S=\sigma(E)$ and finishing the proof, but I'm stuck in this.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: Could you please define the different terms further (e.g. what is $E$, what is $P(X)$, what is $\sigma(E)$, what do you mean by "numerable" (countable?), why are you suddenly talking about a "subfamily"...). I am asking because I find the wording hard to comprehend.

Comment: @Julien $\mathcal P(X)$ is a common notation for the set of subsets of $X$. $E$ is what it says: a subset of $\mathcal P(X)$. $\sigma(E)$ is again standard notation for the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which contains $E$. "Numerable" should have indeed been "countable": it's most likely a mis-translation from the native language. As far as I know, outside of some extremely formal context, "family" = "set", though perhaps "family" may be used either for a set which can be "indexed" (instead of the less evocative technicality of "a function $f$") or for a subset of $\mathcal P(X)$.

Comment: @squird37 By the way, there must be some mistyping in the question: it is apparent that a generic element of $\sigma(E)$ cannot be contained in a subset of $E$. What did we bother with all that "the smallest $\sigma$-subalgebra containing $E$" for, then?

Comment: That is why I got stucked in the first place. I believe this should read "$A \in \sigma(E_{0})$"... which makes the problem much clearer now.

Comment: For any $e\in E$, you want to show $e\in S$.  In other words, you want to find some $E'$ such that $e\in \sigma(E')$.  Do you have any thoughts on what you might choose $E'$ to be?

Comment: I would try to show that every element of $\sigma(E)$ is in fact a countable union of countable intersections of (elements of $E$ or complements of elements of $E$ or $\emptyset$ or $X$). This seems unelegant but rather easy to verify?

Comment: @Julien $\sigma(E)$ is much larger than the set of... There is an entire theory regarding this issue (see Borel hierarchy).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The punchline is that ${S}$ contains ${E}$ because for any $A \in {E}$, $A \in \sigma(A)$ hence $A \in S$ by definition of $S$.

Comment: Thanks @Project Book.

Comment: I believe you can't use such an argument because $A$ does not necessarily belong to $E$ (which would be necessary in order to directly invoke the definition of $S$ by using your argument that $A \in \sigma(A)$)

Comment: @Julien I believe you are sorely mistaken.

Comment: Maybe... Could you please explain how you go from "$A \in \sigma(A)$" (which is correct) to "$A \in S$ by using the definition of $S$"? $A$ is not necessarily included in $E$, therefore there is no "obvious" $E'$ for which we can conclude $A \in \sigma(E')$?

Comment: @Julien I suggest you read my answer carefully (it's not that long) AND what the OP wrote in his/her original post.

Comment: You're correct, I realize what I missed!